# internal server error while deploying django app

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am getting a 500 internal server error while deploying a django app to aws. I cannot find any error in activity log.The nevironment is created and the app is deployed successfully but it is showing this error when I am trying to run it. Can someone please help me to fix the issue ? 
I have added both the text and images of the error log. Thanks.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/error_log
-------------------------------------
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433306 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433311 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433316 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433321 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433325 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433330 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433335 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433339 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433344 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433357 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]   File "/opt/python/current/app/totaliQ/settings.py", line 29
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433364 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]     ALLOWED_HOSTS = [vir-env1.kkhhumhvum.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com]
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433392 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204]                                                                   ^
[Mon May 28 14:23:48.433399 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:204] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.617673 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820] mod_wsgi (pid=4775): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/totaliQ/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.617721 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820] mod_wsgi (pid=4775): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/totaliQ/wsgi.py'.
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.617965 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618019 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "/opt/python/current/app/totaliQ/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618023 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618029 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618033 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618038 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618041 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618046 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618049 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]     self._setup(name)
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618054 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618066 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618071 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618075 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618079 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618082 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618087 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618092 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618097 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618102 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618107 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_module
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618111 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_code
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618116 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618121 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618146 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]   File "/opt/python/current/app/totaliQ/settings.py", line 29
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618154 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]     ALLOWED_HOSTS = [vir-env1.kkhhumhvum.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com]
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618206 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820]                                                                   ^
[Mon May 28 14:23:54.618213 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:15820] SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Mon May 28 14:24:00.753060 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:200] mod_wsgi (pid=4775): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/totaliQ/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Mon May 28 14:24:00.753109 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:200] mod_wsgi (pid=4775): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/totaliQ/wsgi.py'.
[Mon May 28 14:24:00.753272 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:200] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon May 28 14:24:00.753323 2018] [:error] [pid 4775] [remote 172.31.30.246:200]   File "/opt/python/current/app/totaliQ/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>



-------------------------------------
/var/log/eb-activity.log
-------------------------------------
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/pip.exe
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/pip3.6.exe
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/pip3.exe
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/pyexpat.pyd
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/python.exe
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/python3.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/python36.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/pythonw.exe
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/select.pyd
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/sqlite3.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/tcl86t.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/tk86t.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/ucrtbase.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/unicodedata.pyd
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/vccorlib140.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/vcomp140.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/vcruntime140.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/winsound.pyd
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/xlwings32-0.11.5.dll
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/Scripts/xlwings64-0.11.5.dll
extracting: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/pip-selfcheck.json
inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/vir-env/pyvenv.cfg
[2018-05-28T14:23:07.865Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Starting activity...
[2018-05-28T14:23:08.526Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03deploy.py] : Completed activity. Result:
Requirement already satisfied: Django==2.0.5 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
Requirement already satisfied: django-appconf==1.0.2 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
 Requirement already satisfied: django-bootstrap3==10.0.1 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 3))
Requirement already satisfied: django-multiselectfield==0.1.8 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 4))
Requirement already satisfied: django-rest-framework==0.1.0 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 5))
 Requirement already satisfied: django-select2==6.0.2 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 6))
Requirement already satisfied: djangorestframework==3.8.2 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 7))
Requirement already satisfied: pytz==2018.4 in /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt (line 8))
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[2018-05-28T14:23:08.526Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04configen.py] : Starting activity...
[2018-05-28T14:23:09.919Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04configen.py] : Completed activity.
[2018-05-28T14:23:09.919Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result:
 Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2018-05-28T14:23:09.919Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2018-05-28T14:23:10.310Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2018-05-28T14:23:10.310Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2018-05-28T14:23:10.325Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Completed activity.
[2018-05-28T14:23:10.325Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Starting activity...
[2018-05-28T14:23:10.358Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0/InfraCleanEbextension] : Completed activity. 
Result:
 Cleaned ebextensions subdirectories from /opt/python/ondeck/app.
[2018-05-28T14:23:10.358Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage0] : Completed activity. Result:
 Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy stage 0 completed
[2018-05-28T14:23:10.359Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage1] : Starting activity...
[2018-05-28T14:23:10.359Z] INFO  [4604]  - [Application update app-29a6-180528_115229@4/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Starting activity...
```

[image: error log[![error log 2[![log3[![log4[![log5]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEXHZ.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BDw1.png)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ8ik.png)

Comment: replace images with text, for other people who will search the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traceback points to invalid syntax in line:

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = [vir-env1.kkhhumhvum.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com]`

Hosts are strings and should therefore be in quotes:

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['vir-env1.kkhhumhvum.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com']`

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to put ' there. It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Stuff like this happens to everyone, I guess. You're overwhelmed with say AWS and you convince yourself it must be AWS and fail to see the obvious.